# How to count occurence of variable eacht time it occurs and remove outliers in R

Tags: r, outliers, find-occurrences

I have a vector. On the hand I want to remove factors, which seem to be classified not correct. For instance the "D" at position 7. As the surroundings are "A" this should be "A" too. I know there must be a rule, for example, if the 3 values before and after an outlier are different it is converged- in this case "D" to "A" , otherwise it is removed like the "C" on position 22.

```
Var = c("A", "A", "A", "A","A", "A", "D", "A", "A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","D", "D","D","D","D","D","D","D", "A", "A", "A", "A","A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C", "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C", "D","D","D","D","D")

Var= as.factor(Var)



   Var2=c("1", "2", "1", "2","3", "2", "1", "2", "2","2", "2", "1", "1",
"1", "2", "1", "2","3", "2", "1", "2", "2","2", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2","3", "2", "1", "2", "2","2", "2", "1", "1", "2","2", "2", "1", "1","2","2", "2", "1", "1",  "2","2", "2", "1", "1", "2","2", "2", "1", "1","2","2", "2", "1", "1", "2","2", "2", "1", "2","2", "2", "1", "1", "2","2", "2", "1", "1", "2","2", "2", "1", "1","1",
 "1","1","1","1","1")

df<- data.frame (Var, Var2)
```

Additionally, I want to count the occurences for each variable, if it occurs. So I do nit want to count the occurences in the whole vector, but a list like this. Ideally with the corrected values.

```
#   Var Occurence
#1  A 6
#2  D 1
#3  A 4
#4  B 10
#5  C 1
#6  B 2 ...
```

I only get to count the values for the whole vector to get with

```
table (Var)
```

By the following code I get a column, which start counting each time the "Var" changes.

```
df$Var <- with(df, ave(Var, FUN = function(x) sequence(rle(as.character(x))$lengths)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be easier with `data.table`.  Do a grouping by the `rleid` (run-length-id) of the 'Var', and get the count (`.N`), then remove the outlier observations by creating a logical expression in `i` (from the `boxplot` outliers)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N, .(Var, grp = rleid(Var))][, grp := NULL][
   !N %in% boxplot(N, plot = FALSE)$out]
```

-output

```
    Var  N
 1:   A  6
 2:   D  1
 3:   A  4
 4:   B 10
 5:   C  1
 6:   B  2
 7:   C 10
 8:   D  8
 9:   A 12
10:   B 12
11:   C 16
12:   D  5
```

---

`rleid` can take multiple input columns as the first argument is variadic (`...`) - from `?rleid`

> rleid(..., prefix=NULL)

> ...   A sequence of numeric, integer64, character or logical vectors, all of same length. For interactive use.

Therefore, if we have multiple columns, either specify the columns or may use `rleidv` and the subset of data.frame/data.table as input

```
setDT(df)[, .N, .(Var,  Var2, grp = rleid(Var, Var2))][,
    grp := NULL][ !N %in% boxplot(N, plot = FALSE)$out]
```